# Clearing By-Passed Disk in a Dell Powervault MD3000i

Tags: dell-powervault

We have a Dell 3000i iSCSI SAN that had a drive go.  We tried popping an off-the-shelf disk in but it didn't work due to Dell requiring custom firmware on the drive.  So we bought a replacement drive from Dell ($250 for a 1TB SATA drive) and put it in, but it's not working either.  The slot in the SAN seems to be marked as by-passed in the MDS management software and doesn't show up at all in SMcli.

Does anyone know how to clear the slot so that we can use our replacement disk, short of clearing the whole config of the SAN and starting from scratch?  I've seen reference to Dell doing this on their support forum, but they always say "contact us by E-Mail and we'll give you instructions."  The MD3000i is no longer a supported component by Dell so they want $600 to even talk to us about the unit, with no guarantee of a solution.